# CSS having button inline with text

Tags: html, css

I am having issues formatting some CSS code with html. I am trying to have the text in line with the 'Delete' buttons. to have them formatted, to the right and 1/4 its size. Also to have the "delete" buttons a line to the input text box I tried to add a  tag to the list but I can not seem to format the output as desired.

Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

HTML:

```
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {


            echo "<form action='add_series.php' name='delete_list' method='POST'>";
            echo $row['series'] . " ";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_series' value=' " . $row['id'] . "' />";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete'>";
            echo "</form>";


        }

    echo "</form>";
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:lightgray; 
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    color: black;
}

html {
    text-align: center;
}

#login
{
  width:30%;
  margin:auto;
  padding:30px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.picture
{
  width:216px;
  height:185px;
  content:url('images/NHCM_Logo.png');
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#login label
{
  display:block;  
  margin-bottom:.25em;
  text-align: left;
}

#login input[type="text"], #login input[type="password"], #login    input[type="submit"]
{
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:0.5em;
}


input[type=text], input[type=date], input[type=password] {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#service_type, #series, #speaker, #users {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;

}
```

Comment: You can float them...

Comment: @Siyah, can you help me with that, with some code?

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/45a83y2v/1/)?

Comment: @DrewKennedy, almost but to have a gap between  the text and the delete button

Comment: Just take my fiddle and on the label styling add `margin-right: **px`, `**` being the value you feel comfortable with.

Comment: @DrewKennedy where in the CSS? I tried messing with it on fiddle and I cannot seem to get the buttons to shift at all

Comment: [Updated the fiddle with spacing](https://jsfiddle.net/45a83y2v/3/). Also commented where the styling would go for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135536/discussion-between-vlad-and-drew-kennedy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to give the answer to Drew Kennedy, he did not post an office answer but he did help me through comments, and the code that worked for me was:

HTML

```
        echo "<div class='list_container'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            echo "<form action='add_series.php' method='POST'>";
            echo "<div class='delete_list'>";
            echo "<label>" . $row['series'] . "</label>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_series' value=' " . $row['id'] . "' />";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='delete_list_button' class='delete_list_button' value='Delete'>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</form>";

        }
    echo "<div>";
?>
```

CSS

```
.delete_list {
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.delete_list_button {
  border: none;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.delete_list>label {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 25px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  display: table-cell;
  table-layout: fixed;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:left;
  text-indent: 50px;
}

.delete_list>.delete_list_button {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.list_container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

  .list_container {
    width: 40%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add inline-block value for display property of inputs:

```
 /*input {
   display:inline-block;
 }*/

 input[type=submit] {
    display:inline-block;
     width: 30%;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     border: none;
     color: white;
     padding: 16px 32px;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 4px 2px;
     cursor: pointer;
 }

 #name1234 {display: inline-block}
```

Note: previous element, before delete button, should be inline-block too.

Comment: would i need to set something like a DIV tag, so I can tell the code just for the 'Delete' buttons?

Comment: Each inline elements needs inline-block value. It just updated for submit buttons.

Comment: I do not want to mess up the other submit buttons, can I just have it for just the delete buttons without messing with all of the submit buttons on the webpage? Like to go by "name='delete_list_button" for the submit button?

Comment: Add id="name1234" to your html tag and use #name1234 css name

Answer (score 0):

Insert your text into a span and add a css class with the following properties:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {


        echo "<form action='add_series.php' name='delete_list' method='POST'>";
        echo $row['series'] . " ";
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<span class='myclass'>Some Text</span>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_series' value=' " . $row['id'] . "' />";
        echo "<input type='submit' class='buttonclass' name='submit' value='Delete'>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</form>";


    }

echo "</form>";
```

Here is the css class:

```
.myclass{ float: left;}
```

Also add the following to your buttons and spans css classes:

```
.buttonclass{ display:block; margin: auto; }
```

Comment: How would i insert a span? And would I insert it before the while loop, or before the echo "$row['series']"?